# Is a self-closing <li> tag valid?

Tags: html

I recently came across some HTML that used self-closing `<li>` tags like so:

```html
<ul>
    <li/>
    <p>Item 1</p>
    <li/>
    <p>Item 2</p>
</ul>
```

This renders correctly in Google Chrome, but the [Mozilla developer documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li) doesn't make any mention of this form and my editor yells at me when I type this. Is this valid HTML?

Comment: HTML renderers are generally built to be very forgiving-- they will attempt to render all sorts of invalid inputs.  However, it is still best to attempt to input valid HTML to avoid any potential issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't. You can test this with [a validator](https://validator.nu/).

The `/` is an error so browsers will ignore it, treating it as a start tag.

The `<p>` elements are therefore children of the `<li>` elements (which they have to be since they aren't allowed to be children of `<ul>` elements).

The next `<li>` (or `</ul>`) implicitly ends the previous `<li>` because the end tag is optional for that element.